# Not able to display my connections using Connections javascript API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am developing a chat application which requires [linkedin](/questions/tagged/linkedin) authentication for its users. I had a look at the sample code on the Connections  [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) API page and wanted to test it out. While the direct link http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_connections/example.html retrieved my connections to perfection, running the code on my localhost yielded no results(no errors though). It simply does not seem to fetch the connections. I tried obtaining the connections in tag:JSON format first, but even this was an exercise in futility. Note however that the Profile API works on both the localhost as well as the example on your page. Please help!!

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't set the JavaScript Domain properly - you need to [set the JavaScript API Domain field](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api) of the Application Settings to `http://localhost` for the application to function when running locally.